# Dynamic loading of Archive content based on custom taxonomy term name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

*Context*

I've created my own custom taxonomy called **kernal-category** using the CPT UI plugin. This taxonomy is hierarchical and will have a large number of secondary, and tertiary categories.

Currently, to load the correct posts linked to the taxonomy terms I have created individual **content-child** pages for each term.

Example; *the term **news** has a page of **taxonomy-kernal_category-news.php***

These are called from my `archive.php` page using the standard `get_template_part( 'content-child', get_post_format() );`

Each of these pages are identical in layout and design apart from the header on each page which should match the taxonomy term.

*Problem*

I'm going to be creating a lot of terms and that would lead to a lot of individual, duplicate pages which feels unnecessary.

Is there a way I can use a single template and somehow take the taxonomy term from the url, use it as a variable and then load the same page with my header text based on the variable? Or obviously a smarter, alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need one template. What you're describing is how things should work, if your templates are written correctly.

In your case you only need `taxonomy-kernal_category.php`. This template will be used for all terms automatically, and the correct posts will be displayed as long as you use [the standard loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/):

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display post content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

So there should be no manual querying of posts with `WP_Query` or anything like that.

To output the name of the current term dynamically, you can use `the_archive_title()`, and the description with `the_archive_description()`.

`the_archive_title()` often prefixes the title with the taxonomy name, like "Kernal Category: News", so if you don't want that yuo can use `single_term_title();`.

Comment: Perfect answer, worked exactly as desired. Thanks.